# Convert and translate a Ruby hash into a human-readable string

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I have the following Ruby hash:

`{"limit"=>250, "days_ago"=>14, "days_ago_filter"=>"lt", "key"=>3}`

I'd like to convert it to a human-readable string and translate some of the values as necessary:

`Limit: 250 - Days Ago: 14 - Days Ago Filter: Less than - Key: D♯, E♭`,

So `lt`, in this case, actually translates to `Less than`. and `3` for `key` translates to `D♯, E♭`.

I'm almost there with this:

```
variables.map {|k,v| "#{k.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')}: #{v}"}.join(' - ')
```

But translating those values is where I'm hitting a snag.

Comment: What snag are you hitting, specifically? What have you tried? As an aside, this code would be easier to read—and much easier to maintain—if you didn't try to put it all in one line. The code for formatting the key (`k.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')`), for example, should just be its own method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using hashes for mapping out the possible values, e.g.:

```rb
days_ago_filter_map = {
  "lt" => "Less than",
  # ...other cases here...
}

musical_key_map = {
  3 => "D♯, E♭",
  # ...other cases here...
}
```

Then you can switch on the `key`:

```rb
variables.map do |key, value| 
  label = "#{key.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')}"
  formatted_value = case key
  when "days_ago_filter" then days_ago_filter_map.fetch(value)
  when "key" then musical_key_map.fetch(value)
  else value
  end
  "#{label}: #{formatted_value}" 
end.join(' - ')
```

Note that if you're missing anything in your maps, the above code will raise `KeyNotFound` errors. You can set a default in your `fetch`, e.g.

```rb
days_ago_filter_map.fetch(value, "Unknown filter")
musical_key_map.fetch(value, "No notes found for that key")
```

Comment: Suggestion: combine all key maps into a single hash so you can dynamically look them up in a much simpler and `nil`-safe fashion: `all_keymap.dig(k, v)`. Loses the ability to specify a default by key, but that wasn't part of the original spec :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create YAML files too for such kind of mappings :

```
values_for_replacement = {
  "lt" => "Less than",
3 => "D♯, E♭"
}
```

you can try following :

```
variables.map {|k,v|
value_to_be_replaced = values_for_replacement[v]
"#{k.humanize}: #{(value_to_be_replaced.present? ? value_to_be_replaced : v)}"}.join(' - ')
```